# want to install peft and accelerate compatible with torch 1.9.0+cu111

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, large-language-model

i want to install peft and accelerate:
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/huggingface/peft.git
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate.git

But as my torch version is 1.9.0+cu111, the latest accelerate doesn't support my torch version.

- The latest accelerate 0.27.0.dev0 requires torch>=1.10.0, which is not compatible to my torch 1.9.0+cu111.
- The latest peft 0.7.2.dev0 requires torch>=1.13.0, is not compatible to my torch 1.9.0+cu111 which is incompatible.

the command i am using is :

```
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/huggingface/peft.git
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate.git
```

My torch and cuda are:

```
import torch

print("torch.__version__", torch.__version__)
print("torch.version.cuda", torch.version.cuda)
print("torch.__config__", torch.__config__.show())
print("torch.cuda.device_count", torch.cuda.device_count())  # Print the number of CUDA devices

import torchvision
print("torchvision", torchvision.__version__)

torch.__version__ 1.9.0+cu111
torch.version.cuda 11.1
torch.__config__ PyTorch built with:
  - C++ Version: 199711
  - MSVC 192829337
  - Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2020.0.2 Product Build 20200624 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
  - Intel(R) MKL-DNN v2.1.2 (Git Hash 98be7e8afa711dc9b66c8ff3504129cb82013cdb)
  - OpenMP 2019
  - CPU capability usage: AVX2

  - CUDA Runtime 11.1
  - NVCC architecture flags: -gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_80,code=sm_80;-gencode;arch=compute_86,code=sm_86;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=compute_37
  - CuDNN 8.0.5
  - Magma 2.5.4
  - Build settings: BLAS_INFO=mkl, BUILD_TYPE=Release, CUDA_VERSION=11.1, CUDNN_VERSION=8.0.5, CXX_COMPILER=C:/w/b/windows/tmp_bin/sccache-cl.exe, CXX_FLAGS=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /w /bigobj -DUSE_PTHREADPOOL -openmp:experimental -IC:/w/b/windows/mkl/include -DNDEBUG -DUSE_KINETO -DLIBKINETO_NOCUPTI -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_XNNPACK -DSYMBOLICATE_MOBILE_DEBUG_HANDLE, LAPACK_INFO=mkl, PERF_WITH_AVX=1, PERF_WITH_AVX2=1, PERF_WITH_AVX512=1, TORCH_VERSION=1.9.0, USE_CUDA=ON, USE_CUDNN=ON, USE_EXCEPTION_PTR=1, USE_GFLAGS=OFF, USE_GLOG=OFF, USE_MKL=ON, USE_MKLDNN=ON, USE_MPI=OFF, USE_NCCL=OFF, USE_NNPACK=OFF, USE_OPENMP=ON, 

torch.cuda.device_count 1
torchvision 0.10.0+cu111
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

try these

```
!pip install -q transformers==4.11.0
!pip install -q peft==0.1.0
!pip install -q accelerate==0.5.0
```